Invalid use of std::ranges / std::filter
Below is a minimal example of an attempt to use the std::ranges library to look at a map<int,...> and return only the first elements such that the int is contiguous starting at one. However, the code crashes while looping through the names at for (auto& name : names) giving ITERATOR LIST CORRUPTED (msvc 2019). I assume i somehow have a reference to a temporary, but I cannot figure out where.
Can anyone help me identify the mistake?
NOTE: I know this is solution not great - it will keep checking after an element fails instead of ending early, and the range only works once, c++23 can use views::zip() with an unbounded views::iota and views::take_while instead.
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <ranges>

struct NameHolder
{
    auto contiguous_indexed_names()
    {
        return grouped_name_sequences | std::views::transform([](auto& group_names) 
        {
            auto sequential_names = group_names.second | std::views::filter([expected = 1](auto& idx_name) mutable
            {
                return idx_name.first == expected++;
            }) | std::views::values;

            return std::forward_as_tuple(group_names.first, sequential_names);
            // solution: return std::tuple<decltype(group_names.first)&, decltype(sequential_names)>(group_names.first, sequential_names);

        });
    }

    void add(const std::string& group, int sequence, std::string name)
    {
        grouped_name_sequences[group].emplace(sequence, std::move(name));
    }

    std::map<std::string, std::map<int, std::string>> grouped_name_sequences;
};

int main()
{
    NameHolder grouped_names;
    grouped_names.add("Group1", 1, "A");
    grouped_names.add("Group1", 2, "B");
    grouped_names.add("Group1", 4, "D");
    for (auto [group, names] : grouped_names.contiguous_indexed_names())
    {
        for (auto& name : names)
        {
            // expect only "A", "B"
            std::cout << name << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


The lambda is not equality-preserving which is required by filter_view, so this is  undefined behavior.

You are returning a reference to a local variable.
auto sequential_names = group_names.second | std::views::filter([expected = 1](auto& idx_name) mutable
{
    return idx_name.first == expected++;
}) | std::views::values;

return std::forward_as_tuple(group_names.first, sequential_names);

Above, sequential_names is a view that you have created on the stack.
std::forward_as_tuple produces a reference to this stack variable, which you are returning.
Accessing this dangling reference is Undefined Behavior.

Here's my first attempt:
auto contiguous_indexed_names(){
    using namespace std::views;
    return grouped_name_sequences
         | drop_while( [](auto& p)
           { return p.first != 1; } )
         | chunk_by( [](auto& a, auto& b)
           { return (a.first + 1) != b.first; } )
         | take(1) | join;
};

I don't claim it is the optimum solution, but it's a simple and readable one. views::drop_while finds the 1 if available and views::chunk_by clusters the view into consecutive indices. If the result is not empty, views::take isolates the first cluster and views::join flattens the single cluster into a single rank range(contrast to range of range).
